# Preferred Representation of a 3D-Plane in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, 3d, geometry, linear-algebra

What is the preferred way of representing a fixed-dimensional plane (struct) in a 3D-graphics when C/C++ is the preferred language.

Should we

1. store the normalized plane normal vector and origo-distance as *separate* entities or should we
2. express them together in a non-normalized vector?

First alternative requires one extra float/double but is other hand more efficient in algorithms that operate on the normal because it is already precalculated. First alternative is also more numerically stable if we vary the normal and offset separately.

Comment: "What's the best representation of object X in language Y" isn't a meaningful question unless you know what kinds of operations you intend to perform on those objects, and what your other constraints might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, C++ is not the best language to work with planes. We can at first think that using four floating point values is a good choice as it fits in a SIMD register in SSE and VMX. So we may have a class with a single 128bits member, first three values represent the plane normal and the last a distance ( juste like homogenous coordinate, a plane do not always needs a normalized normal if we only care about the sign of a distance test ).

But when we works with planes to categorize points, sphere, and other volumes, implementing a single plane to point distance function will result to sub-optimal algorithm because most of the time, we know we will test a lot of points against a small number of planes. There is room for optimization !

The problem here has a name, in fact, not the problem, but the way we may represent the information. It's Array Of Structures versus Structure of Arrays ( AOS vs SOA ).

A common exercice in a 3D engine is bounding volume frustum culling ! An usual frustum is made of 6 planes, the right representation is not a Frustum class with a `std::array<Plane,6>` member, but most likely, 8 SIMD registers layout as : `{ P0X, P1X, P2X, P3X }, { P4X, P5X, FREEPLANE1X, FREEPLANE2X }, ...` and so on for Y, Z and D. Not  C++, but much better for SIMD programing.

It may also be useful to prefer a SOA reprensation for points too.

Conclusion : The best representation depends on what algorithm and what kind of data set will go thought your planes.